# HTML CSS / cursor pointer

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет!

Мне надо сделать, чтоб при наведение на картинку на неё накладывалась прозрачно-тёмная плёнка, на которой будет заголовок и кнопка на которую можно нажать. Проблема следующая: плёнку я накладываю, заголовок есть, а вот cursor: pointer не устанавливается на кнопку, я не знаю как это решить.

Вот мой код: https://liveweave.com/WcO7K3

Курсор должен появиться на белом квадрате, который появляется при наведение мышкой на картинку.

Вот фигма как должно быть:
https://www.figma.com/file/gBEwh0z9OcWrV6TGs8H2Ij/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=27%3A53

Раздел "My portfolio", там есть пример того как должно быть.

Comment: `.container__pic img:hover + .pic__desc { display: block; }` - Попробуйте это. (Должно работать без JS). P.S. Не забудьте кликнуть на фрейм с превью чтобы браузер сфокусировался на него.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо, так удобнее, чем с JS. А Вы не знаете как можно всё же добавить cursor:pointer на белый квадратик, который отображается во время наведения на картинку?

Comment: Не видел никакого белого квадратика в [вашем примере](https://liveweave.com/sOot8H), можете дополнить ваш пример? (В вопросе, не на сайте в ссылке, вопрос можно изменить нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1436656/edit))

Comment: @ΝNL993 Перейдите пожалуйста ещё раз, я исправил.

Comment: В примере кода не видно кнопок и квадратиков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение вашей проблемы на чистом CSS:

```css
.container__pic img:hover + .pic__desc {
  display: block;
}

.pic__desc:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Небольшое объяснение:

При наведении курсора на изображение следующий элемент с классом `.pic__desc` получет пропорцию `display: block`, далее если курсор был наведён на `.pic__desc`, то также выдать ему `display: block`.

При наведении на `.pic__info` у меня курсор становится указателем, убедитесь что системно обычный курсор у вас отличается от указателя.

Comment: Большой спасибо Вам. Я так понял, что у нас  `.pic__desc` при наведение на картинку становился просто видимым, но браузер не делал его видимым для нашей мышки и следовательно мы сделали его видимым для мышки благодаря псевдоклассу `:hover`.

Comment: @RonaldReagan да всё верно, постарайтесь [изучить CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS) подробней, вам он будет даваться легче.

Comment: @NNL993 Спасибо большое, кажется будто тут всё необъятное )